# Is it better to take a high resolution photo and then resize it than to take it at lower resolution?

Tags: resolution

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does it give higher quality to shoot in low-res mode in-camera, or to downsize high-res photos later?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/11074/does-it-give-higher-quality-to-shoot-in-low-res-mode-in-camera-or-to-downsize-h)

Compare these two scenarios (using the same camera):

1) You take a picture with resolution 3200x2400, transfer it to a computer and resize it to 1600x1200.

2) You take a picture with resolution 1600x1200 and then transfer it to a computer.

Will the picture in 1) be better than the picture in 2)?

Answer (score 2):

Generally, computer software features a lot more sophisticated algorithms and coupled with the processing power of a computer will likely yield better results.  You also have a lot more control over the appearance of final resized image and its compression. When I resize images for emailing or for posting on a website, I prefer to use Adobe Photoshop or Lightroom over say Picassa because the results out of the Adobe software are better.

Comment: Could you post any examples to illustrate how Adobe results are better?