# What is the best way to downsample photos to increase sharpness

Tags: sharpening, algorithms

What is the best way to downsample photos to increase sharpness?

If I have a photo in raw format with a resolution of about 24MP. How do I best downsample it to increase sharpness if I think the original is soft? I’m avare that this will reduce maximum print size for a given dpi but I am wondering what the best downsampling method is.

My intuition tells me that scaling down by an integer factor using area avarage probably is quite good but can I use more information to get even better results?

Can the knowledge of raw pixel values before debayering be used for example?

This differs from this ([How to preserve detail when downscaling scanned photos?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/9770/how-to-preserve-detail-when-downscaling-scanned-photos)) question in that that question wants to preserv grain charachteristics which as far as I understand can be comparativly high contrast micro structure. While this question asks about how to increase sharpnes of soft photos (most likely from a soft lens) which is a more gradual smear.

Comment: Nice question. But I would not limit the question to Downsampling only.

Comment: Related: [How to preserve detail when downscaling scanned photos?](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/9770)